# /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2: No such file or directory error

Tags: linux, docker, ubuntu, linux-kernel, docker-machine

**Background**

I am using docker to do a school project. Specifically, I pulled an ubuntu image and here is the system config:

[image]

I then logged into the docker container (ubuntu) and set up elasticsearch. When I try to run

```
./bin/elasticsearch
```

I get the following error inside the docker container's terminal

```
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2: No such file or directory
```

I have two main confusions:

1. what does that even mean?
2. How to solve it?

Comment: Please show the exact steps you are running with a copy and paste from the command line. Include the command run, it's output, and post it as formatted text rather than a screenshot. This should include the steps taken to start ubuntu and install/setup elasticsearch.

Answer (score 191):

If you are running this on an M1 macbook, it's possible that you are running a native Arm image of ubuntu, instead of the emulated x86 image. If the elasticsearch distribution you are trying to install is for x86_64, then it attempts to link to the x86-64-native ld.so, which of course isn't present on different platforms.

Either install the package for the arm platform specifically if they provide one, or - more likely - run docker explicitly as the emulated x86_64 platform:

```
docker run --platform linux/x86_64 <image>
```

Comment: *many* hours of searching, and finally found this, it was the missing piece of the puzzle. My use case was a bit different, but ultimately same root cause.

Comment: thank you so much, I've encountered the same problem on M1 with `docker build` command. `docker build --platform linux/x86_64` helped!

Comment: me too. I'm new to Mac world and your answer has saved a lot of my time figuring it out. thanks

Comment: My god this is the answer. Thank you so much!  Also on M1 Pro here.

Comment: sure it works, but it's SLOW as hell because it uses emulation then :(

Comment: Same case for me, have to live with the emulation.

Answer (score 34):

For docker-compose, add `platform: linux/x86_64` according to [the docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/#platform)

```
services:
  my-app:
    platform: linux/x86_64
```

Answer (score 5):

No idea what you are running in your container but for me, the reason was simply because a package (Prisma https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/8478#) did not find openssl packages and installing them on `alpine` image failed even with `openssl` manually installed.

It was fixed by switching to `slim` image and installing openssl with `apt-get update && apt-get -y install openssl`. I highly recommend not changing your platform since with my M1 the build time increased by 200s using `linux/x86_64`.

Answer (score 3):

Completing @misnomer answer, I could not even build the image.
If that is the case just add `FROM --platform=linux/x86_64 ...`, from [this source](https://FROM%20--platform=linux/x86_64). Ex: `FROM --platform=linux/x86_64 python:slim ...`