# How to make docker-compose work on M1 chip?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, apple-m1

I'm new to m1 macbook and face an issue with running my docker-compose which looks like this:

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  search:
    platform: linux/x86_64
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.kubectl
```

And the Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y apt-transport-https curl gnupg2 unzip
RUN curl -s https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | apt-key add -
RUN echo "deb https://apt.kubernetes.io/ kubernetes-xenial main" | tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/kubernetes.list
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y kubectl

RUN curl "https://awscli.amazonaws.com/awscli-exe-linux-x86_64.zip" -o "awscliv2.zip" && unzip awscliv2.zip && rm awscliv2.zip
RUN ./aws/install
```

After running it I get such an error:

```
2021-09-30T13:24:52.816038712Z /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2: No such file or directory
```

What exactly are steps to fix this? My Docker version is 4.1.1

Comment: Your physical hardware isn't `x86_64`; why are you trying to set the wrong architecture?

Comment: @DavidMaze it was advised in answer for this question btw. And I'm asking for the correct way for m1 arch

Answer (score 25):

For me i added `platform: linux/amd64`.

Example:

```html
version: "3.7"

services:
  search:
    platform: linux/amd64
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.kubectl
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe the image you are running is for x86_64 platform, hence it tries to find x86-64.so, but you are on an arm machine, so it does not work. You can either install the image for arm64 or try running the command like this:

```
docker run --platform linux/x86_64 <image>
```

Comment: Credits: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69075554/12805063

Comment: I have platform specified in docker-compose described in question and it is linux/x86_64. When i run my docker-compose with this platform i get such error:
Error response from daemon: image with reference search was found but does not match the specified platform: wanted linux/amd64, actual: linux/arm64/v8
What is the right way to run docker-compose to avoid this?

Comment: Please flag this question as a duplicate of the other, if they have the same answer.