# "Failed to initialize Lua VM with Passenger on Docker

Tags: docker, nginx, lua, passenger, apple-m1

I'm trying to setup a development environment that uses docker but the passenger docker image gives me this error over and over again.

```
[1] development-passenger-1  | 2022/04/28 10:17:53 [error] 148#148: failed to initialize Lua VM in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:66
[1] development-passenger-1  | 2022/04/28 10:17:56 [error] 159#159: failed to initialize Lua VM in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:66
```

Using an M1 Mac and I'm new to this whole Mac thing so not sure what's wrong.
Our setup has worked without any issues on linux, windows and older macs. Although I'm happy to change my setup from the Master branch just to get this working but ideally it'll be something that works on all platforms.

Docker desktop gives me a `!amd64` warning for the passenger container.

I've installed OpenResty and Rosetta, changing platforms for passenger, and basically everything else I could find. Best I could do was get rid of the `!amd64` warning but not the Lua VM error.

I can attach more details like parts of our docker-compose or passenger config if need be, but I don't think those will be too helpful at this stage.

Comment: We have the same issue on our side. I hope someone finds a idea for this...

Comment: @tiefenb Did you guys manage to find a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this exactly helps but you could try to build your docker image with `platform: "linux/amd64"`

I read something about this here:

https://erica.works/docker-on-mac-m1/

[How to make docker-compose work on M1 chip?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69708866/how-to-make-docker-compose-work-on-m1-chip)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I did try this before but it doesn't work in this case with Passenger unfortunately.

Comment: Next idea would be to add platform: "linux/arm64/v8" to the nginx image

Comment: Yeah that doesn't fix the main issue with Lua VM, but it does get rid of the warning on docker.

Comment: did you find a way to fix the issue ?