# Docker build Errors

Tags: dockerfile, apple-m1

I'm attempting to run a build of an image on my M1 MacBook. The first attempt built fine, but when pushed to the remote machine I got an exec error. I then modified by Dockerfile in the same way I did last week, specifying the architecture.

```
# get node distro - should be consistent across environments
FROM --platform=linux/amd64 node:16.3-alpine

# copy package.json etc FIRST. any changes here invalidate cache for rest of file
# see https://docs.semaphoreci.com/article/81-docker-layer-caching
COPY package.json package-lock.json app/

# create home dir, where the app will be run
WORKDIR /app

# install our dependencies, for now we want to install ALL deps, including dev ones
# put before COPY, any changes in the cwd will invalidate the cache for this layer
RUN npm ci --platform=linux --progress=false

# below this point we don't need to worry about the cache
# copy everything not in .dockerignore to /app
COPY . $WORKDIR

# make sure we're not running root
USER node

# make sure node is owned by non-root user, otherwise node app will exit with 1
COPY --chown=node:node . /app

# expose ports to outside world
EXPOSE 3001

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

During the build I'm now getting an error that I don't know how to address:

```
#9 190.5 npm ERR! code 1
#9 190.5 npm ERR! path /app/node_modules/gifsicle
#9 190.5 npm ERR! command failed
#9 190.5 npm ERR! command sh -c node lib/install.js
#9 190.5 npm ERR! compiling from source
#9 190.5 npm ERR! Command failed: /app/node_modules/gifsicle/vendor/gifsicle --version
#9 190.5 npm ERR! qemu-x86_64: Could not open '/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2': No such file or directory
#9 190.5 npm ERR!
#9 190.5 npm ERR!
#9 190.5 npm ERR! gifsicle pre-build test failed
#9 190.5 npm ERR! Error: Command failed: /bin/sh -c autoreconf -ivf
#9 190.5 npm ERR! /bin/sh: autoreconf: not found
#9 190.5 npm ERR!
#9 190.5 npm ERR!
#9 190.5 npm ERR!     at /app/node_modules/bin-build/node_modules/execa/index.js:231:11
#9 190.5 npm ERR!     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
#9 190.5 npm ERR!     at async Promise.all (index 0)
#9 190.7
#9 190.7 npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
#9 190.7 npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2022-08-02T20_06_22_654Z-debug.log
------
failed to solve: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = executor failed running [/bin/sh -c npm ci --platform=linux --progress=false]: exit code: 1
make: *** [build] Error 17
```

Comment: Per my finding: try to downgrade ```gifsicle``` from 5.x to 4.x in package.json

Comment: `RUN npm install`  can you add after `USER node`

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps an issue with running native version instead of emulated x86, as mentioned on this stack overflow:

[/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2: No such file or directory error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68630526/lib64-ld-linux-x86-64-so-2-no-such-file-or-directory-error)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/69075554

Answer (score 0):

The solution ended up being a variation of the advice given. I used a different distro flag

```
FROM --platform=linux/amd64 node:16.3.0
```